# Random number generator acting strange

Tags: java, random

I wanted a random number ranging from 0 to 3 and tried the following code just to see how it works.

```
int[] count = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int t = (int)(Math.round((Math.random() *3)));

        count[t] +=1;

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(count[i]);

    }
```

Weird thing now is that 0 and 3 hit about half the times 1 and 2 hit, how is that possible?

Comment: Rounding. From 0 to 0.5 becomes 0 - from 2.5 to 3 becomes 3. 1.5 to 2.5 is twice as wide an interval, so twice as likely to be hit. Use `floor` instead of `round` for uniform results.

Comment: Myself, I'd use the Random class's `nextInt(4)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)

> Returns the closest long to the argument. The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting the result to type long.

You're creating buckets of unequal size:

0 - 0.4999...  => 0    (.5)

0.5 - 1.499...  => 1   (1)

1.5 - 2.499...  => 2   (1)

2.5 - 2.99999...  => 3  (.5)

To fix, either use:

```
Random.nextInt(4);
```

Er... typo, thanks @TedHopp - I mean:

```
Random r = new Random();
...
r.nextInt(4);
```

Or do

```
(int) (Math.random() * 4);s
```

Which will do what you expect.

Comment: Or better, create a `java.util.Random` object and use `nextInt(4)`.

Comment: Note with Math.random(), it will never equal 1.00. This means that when casting to an int, the max value is n-1 assuming `Math.random() * n`.

Comment: @Legend Indeed - which is why I set n = 4 when looking for a range from 0 to 3.

Comment: @TedHopp - bah - that's what I meant.   What I wrote doesn't exist or make sense.

Comment: I was making the notation for @Tricky, just incase he was wondering :)

Answer (score 6):

Look at the intervals that round to each integer:

```
|----+----|----+----|----+----|
0         1         2         3

<...>
Rounds to 0
     <........>
     Rounds to 1
               <........>
               Rounds to 2
                         <....>
                         Rounds to 3
```

You can see that the range that round to 0 and 3 is half the size as the others, so if you choose uniformly you hit them half as often.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are rounding. 0 can only be rounded to if its less than 0.5. However 1 could be picked if its between 0.5 and 1.5. Therefore giving it twice the chance of occurring. The same thing happens for 2, between 1.5 and 2.5. And 3 is only from 2.5 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Math {
    ...
    public static long round(double a) {
       return (long)floor(a + 0.5d);
    }
    ...
}
```

There is more probability to hit 1 and 2

```
int t = (int)(Math.ceil((Math.random() * 4))) - 1;
```

Using ceil instead of round gives better distribution:

```
250
239
242
269
```